# GCP Cloud Function is executed multiple times when invoked from browser

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cors

When executing a Cloud Function triggered by HTTPS requests, while making a POST request in the script, it only executes once, but when making a GET request from the web browser(Edge or Chrome), it executes about three times.

```
@functions_framework.http
def sample_function(request):

"""HTTP Cloud Function.
Args:
    request (flask.Request): The request object.
    <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#incoming-request-data>
Returns:
    The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
    Response object using `make_response`
    <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.make_response>.
"""

if request.method == "OPTIONS":
    # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
    # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
    headers = {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Max-Age": "3600",
    }
    return ("", 204, headers)

output = do_something(request)
headers = {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}

return (output, 200, headers)
```

[image: log]

userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; MicrosoftPreview/2.0; +https://aka.ms/MicrosoftPreview) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36"

userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/119.0.0.0 OneOutlook/1.2023.1114.100"

userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/119.0.0.0"

If anyone knows the cause, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: What's your HTML code? Normally POST generate 2 requests: Options + Post HTTP Verbs

Comment: I input the Cloud Function URL directly into the browser for GET requests. Parameters are appended to the end of the URL like ?param1=A&param2=B, etc. For POST requests, I use the C# code to send the request, and it executes only once.

Comment: We cannot see the URL being requested. Browsers often request additional well-known URLs such as `favicon.ico`. **Do not use screenshots**. Post the logs as text in your question.